# MySQL - Multiplying Time Type Values - Some return 00:00:00

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, time

I'm trying to multiplay a field of type `time`. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. This is in phpmyadmin with MySQL.

Things I have tried already:

- I have tried googling 'sql multiplying time type returns 00:00:00'
  but have no luck with that or similar searches.
- I ran a python script that pulled all these times and multiplied them
  by 6 and 11 and all of them worked - there were no 00:00:00.
- I have also tried doing it individually on a row, and it didn't work
  for the same ones.

Below are pictures before and after I run this query:

```
UPDATE journeys, travel_type
SET journeys.jo_duration = journeys.jo_duration * travel_type.tt_duration_multiplier
WHERE journeys.jo_type = travel_type.tt_id
```

I get no errors.

Some probably helpful information:
`Type 1 means 11` - so I want the value in jo_duration to be multiplied by 11. `Type 3 means 6` (same principle). 2 means 1 (so nothing changes).

There are more rows in this table that have this problem but I didn't want to screenshot the whole table. I thought this should be enough. There are 70 total rows. When I run the above query it says '47 rows affected' (when all rows should technically be affected I think?). I'm not sure if the remaining aren't affected because they're type 2 or if they're the ones being turned to 00:00:00 (or both)?

If you need more information, feel free to ask!

As you can see below, rows with `jo_id; 1, 3, 4, 6 are 00:00:00`. But others multiply correctly?

Does anyone know why this is? And how I can prevent it?

Sorry for the long post and I hope my problem has made sense!
Thank you!

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly multiply number to a time datatype.

Use function time_to_sec and sec_to_time:

```
update journeys, travel_type
set journeys.jo_duration = sec_to_time(
                            time_to_sec(journeys.jo_duration)
                                * travel_type.tt_duration_multiplier
                            mod  86400)
where journeys.jo_type = travel_type.tt_id
```

`mod  86400` is there to remove the day part if the time becomes more than a day

Comment: Worked perfectly! I removed the 'mod 86400' part as it generated errors - 'Unrecognized Keyword. (near mod)' and 'Unrecognized Token. (near 86400'. Thanks a lot @GurV!